# How can a Magi become a ghola (as in Dune by Frank Herbert)?

Tags: ars-magica-5, ars-magica

In Frank Herbert's novel *Dune*, a **ghola** is a postmortem clone with all the memories, abilities and skills of his previous lives. How can a Magi become a ghola?

What hermetic breakthroughs are needed? How do we organize the research? And finally, how to define that in terms of rules?

The reasoning of the Magi is that he does not want to become immortal outside the cycle, but to be reborn for a new cycle while retaining what he was before.

Comment: There is one huge problem, twilight. It doesn't matter how long the magi goes on, twilight will get him eventually. And if you say the new incarnation starts at 0 twilight, then you are breaking one of the core mechanics that keep magi from become too godlike.

Comment: But this falls into homebrew territory, since there is nothing in the reference material for that. We have to [close it as too broad](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6856/11402) (meta).

Comment: @Mindwin Questions can be asked to which there is no RAW answer without them being "opinion-based" or requesting homebrew material. The question simply must be able to HAVE a best-answer that is NOT primarily opinion-based. Sometimes that means the best answer is "The rules don't say". Sometimes that's extrapolation from what the rules do say. I see no reason that this question cannot be answered within the context of the rules. (I mean, seriously, Ars Magica has rules for everything. There's got to be something in there that can be extrapolated from.)

Comment: @WesleyObenshain if the question was something like "would such an interpretation of this plus that rule be applicable to turn a magus into a ghola?", then it probably could have a mostly definitive answer. The way it is, it is too broad.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain  - **We are not writers-for-hire to give one content one asks for.** -  This is why *"homebrew this for me"* is a closeable type of answer. We don't know what OP wants exactly as in a concrete case. In an open-magic system like ars magica, there are 1000's of ways to accomplish something. See that I already posted a comment asking OP to clarify the question **before voting to close.** And you are mistaken, i voted to close as too broad. not POB.

Comment: The ArM sourcebook "Thrice Told Tales" has a story arc involving Damhan-Allaidh, who (I think) uses a range of magical techniques to restore his life/youth again and again (see the appendix p134 for a run down on the overall story). I am certain that you will not find a RAW/Canonical hash of Dune and ArM in the suggested manner - it is too homebrew.

Comment: ... quoted the section in TTT "It was they who taught the
Pictish priests the mystery of the External Soul, and were able to transmigrate their essence from one body to another as a means to escape death."

Comment: Sorry if my question is so "homebrew". Close it, if you want.

Comment: Thanks to @ironboundtome, i'm going to read TTT ;)

The question, can be resumed at : if a magus can "import" him permanently in a new corpse to continue his life. Are rule of essential nature is broken ?

Comment: @user42539 - I don't think RAW defines essential nature enough to know it woudl break in those circumstances, but I'm not sure. Sorry!